# Erro nodeJS: A partials dir must be a string or config object

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

Estou enviando e-mails padronizados usando o nodemailer com o nodemailer-express-handlebars ,mas sempre que estou tentando enviar um e-mail, estou recebendo o

> Error: A partials dir must be a string or config object.

Eu não sei qual é o problema.

```
const path =  require('path');
const nodemailer = require ('nodemailer');
const hbs = require('nodemailer-express-handlebars');

const { host, port, user, pass } = require('../config/mail.json');

const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host,
    port,
    auth: {user, pass },
  });

  transport.use('compile', hbs({
      viewEngine: 'handlebars',
      viewPath: path.resolve('./resources/mail/'),
      extName: '.html',
  }));

  module.exports = transport;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pesquisando sobre o assunto achei esse link que pode ser útil: https://github.com/yads/nodemailer-express-handlebars/issues/22

Parece que precisa que você adicione a propriedade `partialsDir` nas opções do Handlebar.

Segue exemplo abaixo retirado do link que enviei acima:

```
const handlebarOptions = {
  viewEngine: {
    extName: '.hbs',
    partialsDir: 'some/path',
    layoutsDir: 'some/path',
    defaultLayout: 'email.body.hbs',
  },
  viewPath: 'some/path',
  extName: '.hbs',
};

transporter.use('compile', hbs(handlebarOptions));
```

Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 4):

Eu estava com esse mesmo erro, e a solução que encontrei foi a seguinte: no teu projeto, abre `node_modules/express-handlebars/lib/express-handlebars.js`. Em`layoutsDir`põe o diretório do template e repete a mesma coisa para o `partialsDir`. Em `defaultLayout` deixa como `undefined`.

```
function ExpressHandlebars(config) {
  utils.assign(
    this,
    {
      handlebars: Handlebars,
      extname: ".handlebars",
      layoutsDir: "./src/resources/mail/", 
      partialsDir: "./src/resources/mail/", 
      defaultLayout: undefined,
      helpers: undefined,
      compilerOptions: undefined
    },
    config
  );
```

Espero que te ajude!

Answer (score 1):

Basta informar o **defaultLayout** como **undefined** e o **partialsDir** com o seu 'path'. Segue o trecho de código a ser corrigido:

```
transport.use('compile', hbs({
    viewEngine: {
        defaultLayout: undefined,
        partialsDir: path.resolve('./src/resources/mail/')
      },
      viewPath: path.resolve('./src/resources/mail/'),
      extName: '.html'
}));
```